# How to install projects without cocoa pods?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have seen various libraries on GitHub that look useful, but only list CocoaPods as an install method. I'm not sure I want to be dependent on CocoaPods, because I'm wary of Apple breaking it in some future OS X/Xcode update. Is there a way to get these libraries into my Xcode project *without* using CocoaPods?

Comment: I would rather not use cocoaPods but it's becoming more common.  There are some conveniences to it.  But I also feel like it's invasive on the project file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Role of CocoaPods is to automate and simplify the process, but you don't need to use CocoaPods if you don't want to. 
In case of "manual installation", usually it would be:

1. download the project from GitHub
2. add the files to Xcode
3. import headers

But there is no universal recipe for every project, it may slightly differ from case to case, but usually it boils down to previously mentioned.
The best way if you don't want to use CocoaPods is to read the project documentation, and study examples if there are any.

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is. Basically you need to download the library project, drag the project into your own project, do some library dependency setup and you're done.

For details, check out https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire for manually adding a Swift library. And https://github.com/jverkoey/ObjQREncoder for manually adding a Objective-C library to your project.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to install things without Cocoapods is to just drag the source code of other projects into your class. For example, most Github projects can be installed via Cocoapods, or you can just drag the relevant source code into your projects. You don't need to drag in all of the project resources, all you need is usually class files